# Como redirigir una pagina jsp a otra con servlets en java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Buenas,mi problema es que tengo un error en el manejo de servlets y no conosco la causa, estoy trabajando jsp con servlets, y del "index.jsp" a "egresado.jsp" funciona de maravilla, pero alli, cuando el cliente hace algun proceso para guardar en la base de datos,quiero que vaya a un servlet, registre, y vuelva al mismo "egresado.jsp"..El me registra en la base de datos, pero no me muestra la pagina "egresado.jsp".
El error y el fragmento de codigo en la pagina de egresado, son los siguientes: [image: Fragmentos de codigo]
Muchas gracias de antemano.

---

Este es el codigo del doPost, del servlet.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {         
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

    String codAlumno = request.getParameter("cod_alumno_registrar");
    String idFormacion = request.getParameter("id_formacion_registrar");
    String tipoFormacion = request.getParameter("tipo_continua_registrar");
    String institucion = request.getParameter("nom_institucion_registrar");
    String departamento="";
    int numMunicipio=0;
    String pais= request.getParameter("pais_registrar");

    if(pais.equalsIgnoreCase("COL")){
        departamento = request.getParameter("departamento_registrar");
        numMunicipio = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("municipio_registrar"));
    }else{
        departamento=null;
    }
    String intAlta=request.getParameter("optAlta");
    String intBaja=request.getParameter("optBaja");
    String intMedia=request.getParameter("optMeMia");
    String intensidad="";
    if(intAlta!=null && intAlta.equals("on")){
        intensidad="AL";
    }else if(intBaja!=null && intBaja.equals("on")){
        intensidad="BA";
    }else if(intMedia!=null && intMedia.equals("on")){
        intensidad="ME";
    }else{
        intensidad=null;
    }

    String fechaInicio= request.getParameter("fecha_inicio_registrar");
    String fechaFin = request.getParameter("fecha_terminacion_registrar");
    String fechaTitulo = request.getParameter("fecha_titulo_registrar");
    String fechaRegistro = request.getParameter("fecha_registro_registrar");

    //FECHAS actual
    Calendar fecha = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int anio = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);


    if(fechaInicio.equals("")){
        fechaInicio = (anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
    }

    if(fechaFin.equals("")){
        fechaFin = (anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
    }


    if(fechaTitulo.equals("")){
        fechaTitulo = (anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
    }


    if(fechaRegistro.equals("")){
        fechaRegistro = (anio+"-"+mes+"-"+dia);
    }


    String usuarioRegistro = request.getParameter("nom_usuario_registrar");


    FormacionContinuaDTO g=new FormacionContinuaDTO();

    g.setId(Integer.parseInt(idFormacion));
    g.setCodalumno("1151124");
    g.setTipocontinua(tipoFormacion);
    g.setInstitucion(institucion);
    g.setPais(pais);
    g.setDepartamento(departamento);
    g.setMunicipio(numMunicipio);
    g.setIntencidad(intensidad);
    g.setFechainicio(Date.valueOf(fechaInicio));
    g.setFechaterminacion(Date.valueOf(fechaFin));
    g.setFechatitulo(Date.valueOf(fechaTitulo));
    g.setFecharegistro(Date.valueOf(fechaRegistro));    
    g.setUsarioregistro(usuarioRegistro);


    ObjetoDAO dao= new ObjetoDAO(false);
    try{

    boolean x=dao.insertarFormacionContinua(g);

    if(x) {
           out.print("Correcto!");  

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/egresado.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //              
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/egresado.jsp").include(request, response);

    } else {
        out.print("Incorrecto!");  
      //            RequestDispatcher 
      rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/egresado.jsp");  
      //            rd.include(request, response);  
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/egresado.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }



    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }







}
```

Comment: Si en vez del e.printStacTrace() imprimes un e.getMessage() qué te muestra? Solo "ArrayOfBoundException"?

Comment: 1) No adjuntes pantallazos con el código, inclúyelo en la pregunta dándole formato (Control+K). 2) Incluye el código relevante al problema, muestras el código de un servlet pero el stacktrace se corresponde con la ejecución de un JSP. Por favor revisa el [help] y [ask].

Comment: Ah, ok muchas gracias,es que uso esto por primera vez, que pena.. 
Respecto al codigo, si, me vota exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: Podes agregar el código de egresado.jsp? En la linea 142 estarías accediendo a un array con un índice que excede la cantidad de elementos del array.

Comment: El jsp es muy extenso, pero la linea 142 es la declaración de  class,style y id de un div.

Comment: Cada JSP es "traducido" automáticamente a un Servlet, y el Servlet es compilado (una vez) y ejecutado (con cada petición), así que la línea que te sale en el stacktrace no se corresponde con tu línea en el JSP, sino en el Servlet. Tienes dos opciones: "adivinar" cuál es la línea que corresponde (¿dónde accedes a elementos de un array? O poniendo mensajes de log para ver la lógica) o buscar en tu servidor, en alguna carpeta temporal, el código "traducido" a Servlet...

Comment: Buenas, @SJuan76 disculpa una pregunta, ¿el error no puede ser de un array que trabajar java por detras?, por que en mi codigo solo uso arrays 
para generar los datos correspondientes de un combo, y no hay ningun error.

Comment: Por lo que recuerdo, el stacktrace indica muy claramente que la excepción se origina (primera línea) en una clase `egresado_jsp.java` (o algo así, no puedo ver las imágenes desde el ordenador del trabajo). Ése es el Servlet correspondiente a tu JSP.

Comment: Ese es el problema, que segun lo que usted dice, el error se origina en la linea 142 del servlet ¿no?, y en esa linea hay la implementacion de un else, que no llega, por que los datos son correctos.